# MYSQL: Find all posts between certain users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

table message (holds the creator of a message and the message)
**id - creatorId - msg**

and a table message_viewers (tells who can read the message msgId)
**msgId - userId**

If I create a message as user 1 and send it to user 2 and user 3, the tables will look like this:

```
tbl_message:  
1 - 1 - 'message'
tbl_message_viewers:  
1 - 2  
1 - 3
```

What I want to do is to fetch the messages that are between the users x1...xN (any number of users) AND ONLY the messages between them.
(Example if users are 1, 2, and 3, I want the messages where the creator is 1, 2 or 3, and the users are 2,3 for creator = 1, 1 and 3 for creator = 2 and 1, 2 for creator = 3)
**I am not interested** by messages between 1 and 2, or 2 and 3, or 1 and 3, but only by messages **between the 3 people**.

I tried different approaches, such as joining the two tables on message id, selecting the messages where creatorId IN (X,Y) and then taking only the rows where userId IN (X, Y) as well. Maybe something about grouping and counting the rows, but I could not figure out a way of doing this that was working.

---

**EDIT: SQL Fiddle here**

---

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/963c0/1**

Comment: does a message require at least one row in tbl_message_viewers?

Comment: Yes. And the creator of the post does not send a message to himself.

Comment: No, it is exclusively between the 3 people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might do what you want:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
INNER JOIN message_viewers mv ON m.id = mv.msgId
WHERE m.creatorId IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND mv.userId IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM message_viewers mv2
    WHERE mv2.msgId = mv.msgId
      AND mv2.userId NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
    )
  AND mv.userId != m.creatorId;
```

The IN's will give the users that created/can see, and the `mv.userId != m.creatorId` are for excluding the creator from the message_viewers table (like you showed in your requirements).

Edit:

With the requirement of only sending messages between those 3 id's, i came up with the following:

```
SELECT m.id,m.creatorId,m.message
FROM message m
INNER JOIN message_viewers mv ON m.id = mv.msgId
WHERE m.creatorId IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND mv.userId IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND mv.userId != m.creatorId
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM message_viewers mv2
    WHERE mv2.msgId = mv.msgId
      AND mv2.userId NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
    )
GROUP BY 1,2,3
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/963c0/21)</kbd>

Comment: This query also return all combinaisons that include 1, 2 and 3, but not exclusively the messages sent and received ONLY by 1, 2 and 3

Comment: @user3010549. Try with this query. i added a not exists to exclude other viewers.

Comment: I get a syntax error when trying your query (doesn't seems to like the EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...

Comment: Sorry. i had a extra mv_userId there. i'm removing it.

Comment: This returns all messages sent between any combinaison of the users, and not strictly between all of them (it can return messages that were only between 1 and 2, or between 2 or 3)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that requirement until now. I'll give it a shot in a bit.

Comment: @user3010549. can you show some sample data and tables structure in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to make it easier to test before posting an updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with join and with IN() clause

```
SELECT * FROM 
tbl_message m
JOIN tbl_message_viewers mv (m.id = mv.msgId )
WHERE m.creatorId IN(1,2,3) AND mv.userId IN(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want the `BETWEEN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
-- returns fieldname 1-10
```

In this case however, `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so you'll need to specify `!=` those conditions as well:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname BETWEEN 1 AND 10 AND fieldname NOT IN (1, 10)
-- returns fieldname 2-9
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: I used user 1, 2 and 3 but it could be between users 1, 17 and 32.

Comment: `...WHERE fieldname BETWEEN 1 AND 17 AND fieldname BETWEEN 17 AND 32 AND fieldname NOT IN(1, 17, 32)`

Answer (score 0):

this worked on oracle

first join gets row count for people we are not interested in
second join gets row count for people we are interested in

the in clauses will need to be generated by some sort of dynamic sql
and number_of_people also needs to be generated somehow.

```
select msgId, count_1, count_2
  from message tm
       join ( select ty.msgId as ty_msgId, 
                     count(ty.msgId) as count_1 
                from message_viewers ty
               where ty.userId not in (:a,:b,:c)
            group by ty.msgId)
         on msgId = ty_msgId
       join (select tz.msgId as tz_msgId, 
                    count(tz.msgId) as count_2 
               from message_viewers tz
              where tz.userId in (:a,:b,:c)
              group by tz.msgId)
         on msgId = tz_msgId
      where createrId in(:a,:b,:c)
        and count_1 = 0
        and count_2 = :number_of_people -1;
```

my sql prefers this

```
select msgId, count_1, count_2
  from message tm
       left join ( select ty.msgId as ty_msgId, 
                     count(ty.msgId) as count_1 
                from message_viewers ty
               where ty.userId not in (:a,:b,:c)
            group by ty.msgId) as X
         on msgId = ty_msgId
       left join (select tz.msgId as tz_msgId, 
                    count(tz.msgId) as count_2 
               from message_viewers tz
              where tz.userId in (:a,:b,:c)
              group by tz.msgId) as Y
         on msgId = tz_msgId
      where createrId in(:a,:b,:c)
        and (count_1 = 0 or count_1 is null)
        and count_2 = :number_of_people -1;
```

Comment: I tried this query using the fiddle (see my updated post) but it doesn't return any result for user 1, 2 and 3